# Delphi generic sorting optimisation

Tags: sorting, delphi, generics

I am mainly interested in stable sorting large arrays of strings. With real-world data I succeed in beating Tarray.sort by a factor 10-100 (even though the latter is not stable). As an exercise I tried to repeat this for simple types. Works fine. And then to bundle it into a generic class as in Tarray. Consider my starting point:

```
procedure sortArray(var values : array of byte); overload;
var temp : array of byte;
  function getSequence(from: integer) : integer;
  procedure doThis(...);
  procedure doThat(...);
begin
  setLength(temp,high(values)+1);
  // actual code calling one of the procedures
end;
procedure sortArray(var values : array of double); overload;
var temp : array of double;
... etc ...
```

All the local subroutines have access to `values` and `temp`.
It seemed to me like an ideal situation to try out how generics work. In a generic class you can't have local subroutines, so these are all changed into methods. I then have:

```
type
  TsimpleArray<T>  = class
  private
    class function getSequence(var values,temp : array of T; from: integer) : integer;
    class procedure doThis(var values,temp : array of T; ...);
    ...
  public
    class procedure sort(var values : array of T); 
  end;
```

Class functions can not have access to global temp storage, so that has to be passed as a parameter to all these methods, as well as the source array. All comaprisons `if v>values[k]` and the like to be changed into `if Tcomparer<T>.default.compare(v,values[k])>0`.
Well, it works. But it is now around 10 times slower then my simple procedure approach. (Still a lot faster than Tarray.sort.) I guess this is the prize we pay for better maintainable generic code. Or are there things I could do better?

Comment: Try passing the result of `TComparer<T>.default` using a parameter to the routines where you need to call the actual compare proc, because it takes time to determine the default comparer of `T`. An extra advantage: you now also make an sort routine with a custom comparer proc which uses the same mechanism 

Comment: Look at the sorting functions on the develop branch of spring4d

Comment: @Hoek: that helped. Generic sort is now 3-4x slower than the regular procedural approach (instead of 10x). Still a hefty price.